# Linux: Can we add TRACE_EVENTS in .h files?

Tags: c, linux

I am newbie to Linux world. And I have to trace the `readl()/writel()` functions. In order to achieve this I tried to add TRACE_EVENTS in `readl()/writel()` function in `arch/arm64/include/asm/io.h`. Let's say i defined trace events in `my_trace.h`. Finally, I call trace function as follows:

```
#include <trace/events/my_trace.h>
....
....
static inline u32 __raw_readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
     u32 val;
     trace_my_function("__hi__", addr);
     asm volatile("ldr %w0, [%1]" : "=r" (val) : "r" (addr));
     return val;
}
```

But, adding the `#incldue <trace/events/my_trace.h>` in `arch/arm64/include/asm/io.h` produces many compiler and linker error. However, including the same `#incldue <trace/events/my_trace.h>` in any `.c` files works fine (that means my trace events are working fine and correct).

**Is it like we can't add trace events in `.h` files ??**
If not where I am doing wrong.

Comment: This may show my ignorance, however; what is 'incldue'.  This, alone could be a root cause of your compile problems.  However, you did mention that you have placed your my_trace.h file in the io.h file.  Which, normally, would work, however any misspelling would result in compile time errors.  What do you mean by 'works fine' Is the __raw_read() function actually invoked?  and where is the trace_my_fuunction() function placed?  Is the function name actually spelled with 'fuunction'?  and finally, what is __iomem?

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry, There are typo here. But at my end code is fine
 'works fine' >>>> means calling the trace function from the c files which satisfied the prototype worked fine. And main problem is not calling the function. But including the `#include <trace/events/my_trace.h>` header  file.

Comment: Consider instead `strace`, Linux userspace probes, `LD_PRELOAD` override.